# How to access current viewmodel from app.xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

When the program closes I want to save any changes to the data. I currently have a method to do so in my *ViewModel*. I have a `OnExit` method in the `app.xaml` file, but how can I access the save-method in the *ViewModel* from here?

**App.xaml.cs**

```
    protected override void OnExit(ExitEventArgs e)
    {
        //This is were I want to access the ViewModel

        base.OnExit(e);
    }
```

**ViewModel.cs**

```
    public void Save(){
        //This method save to the DB
    }
```

Comment: Please add code.... what are we supposed to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using the Observer Pattern.
Register your view-models as subscribers to an App's Close event.
When the app's close event is triggered, notify your subscribers (i.e. view-models) so that they can react to that event.

- Prism provides an EventAggregator.
- Xamarin.Forms provides a MessagingCenter.
- Bizmonger provides a MessageBus.

You can use a mediator like the ones specified to manage a publisher / subscribe model without the classes knowing about each other.